# Nonzero idempotents in compact semitopological semigroups with zero

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

Let $S$ be a compact semitopological semigroup. Then, $S$ contains minimal idempotents by Ellis' theorem.

> **Ellis' Theorem:** In a compact left-topological (resp. right-topological) semigroup, every right (resp. left) ideal contains a minimal right (resp. left) ideal, which contains an idempotent.

If $S$ contains a zero element $0$, then $0$ is the sole minimal idempotent that Ellis' theorem provides.

**Question:** Is there a variant of Ellis' theorem for compact semitopological semigroups with $0$, which guarantees the existence of $0$-minimal idempotents, especially when $S$ is **not** $0$-simple?

Let's assume that no left, right, two-sided ideal $I\subseteq S$ with more than $2$ elements satisfies $I^2=\{0\}$.

---

**Terminology:** If $p,q\in S$ are two idempotents, then $p\leq q$ if $qp=p=pq$. An idempotent $p\in S$ is minimal if $q\leq p\Rightarrow q=p$ for all idempotents $q\in S$, $p$ is $0$-minimal if $p\neq 0$ and $0\neq q\leq p\Rightarrow q=p$ for all idempotents $q\in S$.

---

**Note:** We cannot expect a verbatim similar version of Ellis' theorem. Indeed, let $A=L^{\infty}([0,1])$ and $S=\{f\in A: \|f\|\leq 1\}$ be the unit ball of $A$ equipped with the pointwise multiplication of functions and the weak* topology. Then, $S$ is a commutative compact semitopological semigroup with $0$ with no $0$-minimal idempotents.

Comment: Even joint continuity won’t get you zero minimal idempotents. Take the free semigroup on a finite set A and adjoin a zero with the zero being a one point compactification. Then you get a compact jointly continuous semigroup with only zero as an idempotent.

Comment: I see. One could take any discrete semigroup and do the same. A variant of Ellis theorem for compact semigroups in this generality is really a theorem for locally compact semigroups without $0$.

Comment: I.don't think you can use just any discrete semigroup.  If G is an infinite group then any infinite sequence $g_n$ will converge to 0 and so with the sequence $g_n^{-1}.$ But the sequence $ g_ng_n^{-1}$ does not.

Comment: But the construction works for any discrete semigroup with a collection of cofinite ideals whose intersection is empty.

Comment: My point is that adding a zero element as a one point compactification does not always yield a jointly continuous multiplication. It might be ok for the one-sided case.  I don't usually think about that.